# Unable to connect to server SQL SERVER 2000 Autenticacion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Necesito realizar una validacion de Hardening para una migracion de base de datos SQL Server 2000 a SQL server 2008, Al tratar de connectarme mediante algun cliente  (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) al SQL Server 2000 o desde LocalHost con (SQL Query Analyzer) con autenticacion SQL arroja el siguiente mensaje

**"Unable to connect to server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"**

El login con el que trato de conectarme ya existe con rol sysadmin en SQL Server 2000, Este Login se creo entrando con autenticacion Windows en la conexion (localhost) , *Adjunto el Log en Imagen solo contiene la informacion del inicio de SQL server es el ultimo que tengo previamente realizando pruebas de login en Localhost*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si editas la pregunta y adjuntas el Log del SQL, para así poder tener una mejor idea, con todo te sugiero que revises el Servicio del SQL en el SQL Server Manager, puede que este inactivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se resolvio el problema, la solucion fue activar el **modo dual de autenticacion** SQL Server y Windows, Anteriormente solo tenia el Modo Windows